# return statement ignored while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, android-studio

i wrote a method that creates a JSONObject, that used to work. suddenly i behaves very strange. with the debugger i can reach the line that returns the created JSONObject, but it always jumps to the last line returning null, without going insid the catch block. the debugger showed me that the created object is a valid JSONObject.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

...

JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();
    try {
        returnJson.put("event", event);
        returnJson.put("list", jsonArray);
        returnJson.put("type", "list");
        returnJson.put("container", container);
        Log.d(TAG, "created");
        Log.d(TAG, returnJson.toString());
        return returnJson;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "null returned"); // never called in the non-debugging mode
    return returnJson;
```

Comment: Does it work properly *not* in the debugger? Perhaps the source the debugger is working with is out of sync with the class files...

Comment: i dont think so. as i can not debug i can just guess, but the porject behaves as if there is no json object returned. anyway, i cleared all caches and restarted, i could not fix any possible out of sync problems that way.

Comment: Well you can easily add *logging* to see exactly how far it goes without debugging...

Comment: There should not be any differences in the flow, debugging or otherwise. Does it still work if you run the application in non-debug mode?

Comment: yes it works in the non-debugging mode. i edited the question. the last log never gets called. so how can i fix the debugging problem?

Comment: Do you have any build path error in project.? If so your source won't be compiled completely.

Comment: no, everything ok. i see now that the debugger also ignored the last log statement as well.

Comment: `i see now that the debugger also ignored the last log statement as well.` Then he's not using the newest version of your code. Try to rebuild the whole project.

Comment: thats what i already did a several times, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it didn't hit the last `return returnJson;` but the former one. I mean the code inside `try` block did *not* throw an exception.

I've witnessed the debugger break on `return` statements that isn't actually hit under some condition I am not well aware of.

I just wrote example code to reproduce:

```
private static String method() {
    try {
        Class clazz = AnyClass.class;
        return clazz.getName();     // place a break point #1
    } catch(Exception ignored) { }

    String result = "An exception caught.";
    return result;                  // place another break point #2
}
```

It will surely break at #1 **and then "stop" at #2**, too. This method actually returns "package.name.AnyClass".